# Typescript : create a string indexed interface with optional properties

Tags: typescript

I'm currently learning how to use TypeScript correctly, and I can't find any references that explain how to declare an interface/type indexed by a string and containing a couple of optional properties.

Here is the code I'm trying to use :

```js
interface MyInterface {
    [key: string]: string;
    foo: string; // <-- Works fine
    bar?: string; // <-- Error, because the property might be undefined ?
}
```

Why is this syntax not valid for the optional property ?
Is it even possible using TypeScript to achieve this ?

Comment: You *could* enable [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJpEVN) to ensure that nobody is allowed to *write* `undefined` to the `bar` property.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Adding 'undefined' on the key as mentioned below solved the problem so I'll try not to modify the compiler options :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given key 1 is considered for all keys, if you want any value to be undefined, you must give undefined type to the first one.

```
interface MyInterface {
   [key: string]: string | undefined;
   foo: string;
   bar?: string;
}
```